# Chart.js - How to draw multiple graphs in one canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

How can I use `Chart.js` to draw multiple graphs in one canvas ? Something [like this](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/wiki/100_115_Multiple_Charts):

[image]

**Note:** I'm using [chartjs-node](https://github.com/vmpowerio/chartjs-node) to generate PNG images on server side. The library is based on `chartjs` and it supports only one canvas at a time, that's why I'm asking for multiple graphs in one canvas.

Comment: I am pretty sure that can not be made.

Comment: They don't support this nor they will any time soon. See this (thread)[https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1624]. Anyway, what's the problem with using multiple canvases?

Comment: Thanks @Phiter, I updated my question above. I'm using `chartjs-node` to generate PNG images on server side. The library is based on `chartjs` and it supports only one canvas at a time, that's why I'm asking for multiple graphs in one canvas.